# Function listed for the onClick event is firing at load time on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is receiving a list of records as a prop. I'm trying to add a function to an onClick event, but the code set to be executed on the click event is firing as soon as the component loads. In this case I'm referring to the processM function. I'm new to ReactJS and I would appreciate any help.

```js
var TempJobTaskActions = React.createClass({
 processM: function(url){

  console.log('in processMove: ', url);

  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   success: function(data){
   }
  });

 },
 render: function(){

  var action = null;
  var downUrl = '../MoveDown?id='+this.props.tid;
  var upUrl = '../MoveUp?id='+this.props.tid;

  if(this.props.position == "solo"){
   action = (<span></span>);
  }

  if(this.props.position == "first"){
   action = (<span><a className='cdc-link cdc-icon glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down' 
    href='#' onClick={this.processM(downUrl)} title='Move Down'></a></span>);
  }

  if(this.props.position == "last"){
   action = (<span><a className='cdc-link cdc-icon glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up' 
    href='#' onClick={this.processM(upUrl)} title='Move Up'></a></span>);
  }

  if(this.props.position == "middle"){
   action = (
    <div>
     <span><a className='cdc-link cdc-icon glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up' 
      href='#' onClick={this.processM(upUrl)} title='Move Up'></a></span>
     <span><a className='cdc-link cdc-icon glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down' 
      href='#' onClick={this.processM(downUrl)} title='Move Down'></a></span>
    </div>
   );
  } 

  return (
   <div>{action}</div>
  );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`this.processM(upUrl)` will call the function. To send variables you should bind like this instead

> this.processM.bind(this, upUrl)

***[Here is a good example with bind](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)***

Comment: that, or you could just make the onclick {this.processM} and set a data attribute. So, data-upurl={upUrl} and inside the function grab it with event.target.dataset.upurl

Answer (score 7):

Try rewriting the call [as an ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
onClick={() => {
  this.processM(downUrl);
}}
```